# failed to read stream, no exist StreamNotFoundError: stream not found

Tags: javascript, database, eventstoredb

As per documentation:

https://developers.eventstore.com/clients/grpc/reading-events.html#reading-backwards-1

under: Checking if the stream exists

```
const events = client.readStream("user", {
  direction: FORWARDS,
  fromRevision: BigInt(10),
  maxCount: 20,
});

try {
  for await (const resolvedEvent of events) {
    console.log(resolvedEvent.event?.data);
  }
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof StreamNotFoundError) {
    return;
  }

  throw error;
}
```

i do get:

```
failed to read stream, no exist StreamNotFoundError: user not found
```

Their tutorials seems outdated for me.

**Q:** Is there a way to check if a stream exist ( and maybe add if not?) in event store in 2022?

Edit 2:

after the attempts, it still shows with the provided answer:
node:events:505
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

```
StreamNotFoundError: user not found
    at ReadStream._transform (game\node_modules\@eventstore\db-client\dist\streams\utils\ReadStream.js:50:32)
```

Comment: Could you provide the full reproduce steps? Did you append events first? Did you check the UI if the stream exists? Does the stream have more than 10 events (you're setting the revision instead of reading since the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you have in your database, but I quickly copied the samples code and it works as expected

```
const {EventStoreDBClient, FORWARDS, StreamNotFoundError, START} = require("@eventstore/db-client");

async function main() {
    const CLOUD_ID = "ca1loplo0aepjgt215o0";
    const client   = EventStoreDBClient.connectionString`esdb+discover://${CLOUD_ID}.mesdb.eventstore.cloud`;

    const events = client.readStream("doesntexist", {
        direction:    FORWARDS,
        fromRevision: START,
        maxCount:     20,
    });

    try {
        for await (const resolvedEvent of events) {
            console.log(resolvedEvent.event?.data);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof StreamNotFoundError) {
            console.log("Stream not found");
            return;
        }

        throw error;
    }
}

main().then(() => console.log("done"));
```

When I run it I get:

```
Stream not found
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems to be that you're trying to check if the stream exists ***after*** it's already finished being called.

It may be helpful to move the `client.readStream()` inside the `try/catch`, await that directly, then loop over as needed. This at least narrows the point at which it's going wrong, and fails before the for loop is begun.

```
try {
// Moved down into try block!
  const events = await client.readStream("user", {
    direction: FORWARDS,
    fromRevision: BigInt(10),
    maxCount: 20,
  });

  for (const resolvedEvent of events) {
    console.log(resolvedEvent.event?.data);
  }
  ...
} catch (error) {...}
```

Comment: Smart idea. but for some reason it still wont work for me.

Comment: @maria unfortunately, since I haven't ever used this service, it's hard to know why. It could very well be something misconfigured in some other part of the code or config in the service itself. That being said, this method at least allows you to correctly, gracefully handle the error. Moreover, i'd try the `readAll()` method that Event Store provides on the client object, then seeing if you get back what's expected when only reading `'user'`

Comment: The answer is incorrect as `readStream` doesn't execute enumeration, so it will never fail. The error is thrown at `for await (const resolvedEvent of events)`